# Reference request: geometric finiteness of Fuchsian groups

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, fuchsian-groups

My limited knowledge on hyperbolic geometry suggests me that the following proposition should be true (please correct me if I'm wrong):

**Proposition.** The convex core of a complete hyperbolic surface has finite area if and only if the surface is of finite type.

> > **Question.** What is the best literature to cite for this result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a theorem of Siegel, and a reference with simple proof is
Theorem XI.12 in
M. Tsuji, Potential theory in modern function theory, Maruzen, Tokyo 1959 (there is an AMS Chelsea reprint, 1975).